# Count matching occurrences in a single line solaris

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, solaris, sunos

Any command in handy to grep for a matching string and count number of occurrence of string when there is a lengthy string which is a single line.

`"grep -i something abc.txt | wc -l"`  works fine  when there are multiple lines but we cannot get count if abc.txt is having single line with multiple occurrences.

PS: I have read multiple links regarding this question but none of them worked for me as I am using Sun OS.  Please keep in mind for Sun OS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about awk:

```
$ cat file
something. something else
not that's something
$ awk 'i=gsub(/something/,"&"){c+=i}END{print c}' file
3
```

It counts matches if it's a part of a longer string (`something.`), like `grep` would.

Comment: @Stunner Because it's unfamiliar to you.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `grep` support the option `-o`? In that case you can use

```
grep -oi something abc.txt | wc -l
```

When this won't work. try a work-around like

```
sed 's/something/&\n/g' abc.txt | grep -ci "something"
```

Answer (score 0):

On Solaris 11, use `/usr/gnu/bin/grep` to make the answers you've found elsewhere using the -o option work.

Comment: There is no gnu folder under /usr ,,  below is output for whereis grep
grep: /usr/bin/grep /usr/man/man1/grep.1

Comment: What version of Solaris are you using?

Comment: Sry for late reply.. Still i haven't found the answer.  It's Sun OS 5.10

Comment: SunOS 5.10 is Solaris 10, so you will have far older and far less software than currently ships in Solaris 11.